# I have Xcode command line tools, do I really need the Xcode GUI to develop iOS apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, ide, command-line-interface

I have to develop an iOS app for college project. On my Mac the Xcode command line tool is installed. I dont want to use the Xcode GUI as it performs very laggy.

My question is, for iOS ap development do I really need the Xcode GUI downloaded from Mac app store, or the command line interface is sufficient?

Comment: If you want a IOS mobile app i. think the cmd is not sufficient as it requires alot of styling and constraints and storyboards and alot so on and on and on and there is absolutely no way you will be able to make it without a GUI

Answer (score 2):

*"I dont want to use the Xcode GUI as it performs very laggy."*

Not necessarily true.

First, there is a big difference between **Xcode GUI** and **Xcode IDE**

If you don't like the **GUI** portion for UI development - i.e. using Storyboard / Interface Builder - you don't have to use that feature at all.

If you don't like the **IDE** as a whole (code-completion, formatting, integrated help, build-run-debug, etc, etc) you don't have to use that either.

For example, you can write your entire app with TextEdit and build it from the command line... if you really wanted to.

However, you *do* have to have the SDK installed, and the best way of doing that (probably the only practical way) is to install Xcode ... but again, you can use any text/code editor you like, and then use the command-line tools for building.

Answer (score -3):

yes you need to, everything that you need to make an app is on the XCode IDE.